# How to add the date to the file name?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

now = datetime.now()
print now #2013-05-23 04:07:40.951726    
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar", "w")
```

How to add the date to the file name? For example: `test2013_05_23_04_07.tar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With string formatting.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

now = datetime.now()
print now #2013-05-23 04:07:40.951726    
tar = tarfile.open("test%s.tar" % now, "w")
```

Or using `.format()` in Python 3.+

```
tar = tarfile.open("test{}.tar".format(now), "w")
```

Note, you can also decide how you want `datetime.now()` to be displayed using `.strftime()`:

```
print now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> 2013-05-23
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a function I use fairly often:

```
def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-{fname}'):
        import datetime
        # This creates a timestamped filename so we don't overwrite our good work
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)
```

invoke with

```
fname = timeStamped('myfile.xls')
```

Result: `2013-05-23-08-20-43-myfile.xls`

Or change the fmt:

```
fname2 = timeStamped('myfile.xls', '%Y%m%d-{fname}')
```

Result: `20130523-myfile.xls`

Comment: I think you mean to call `fname = timeStamped('myfile.xls')`

Answer (score 4):

I usually use something like this:

```
tst = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat("-").split(".")[0].replace(":","-")
tar = tarfile.open("test%s.tar" % now, "w")
```

produces filename `test2013-05-23-14-37-51.tar`.

Comment: That is needlessly complex, you can just use `.strftime()` and specify the format.

Comment: It is not simple, but for me it is harder to remember method name strftime and ftime format it uses.