# Update file name and path using python

Tags: python

Below is my API code where I am trying to update the file path on a daily basis to run an API call.

I am unable to determine how I can update the file name on a daily basis. Some help would be highly appreciated.

```py
import requests

url = "*******"

payload = {'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
           'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
           'name': 'file'}
files = [
  ('file', open('/C:/Users/SET/Desktop/TEST/TEST/test_test_test_file_20201001.csv','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'X-API-TOKEN': '*******'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Is it specifically the `test_test_test_file_20201001.csv` part you want to update? If so, should it be todays date?

Comment: Yes That's the part I want to update

Comment: So basically test_ will be my regex and the rest of the file name will be updated on a daily basis

Comment: Something similar to this 

pattern='test_*.csv'

Comment: I understand what you want, I don't understand what exactly is the problem. Are you having problem running the script daily? Are you having trouble changing the path? How do you expect to change it? If you change, how do you know if there going to be a file with that name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create a file name with the current date & time in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607688/how-to-create-a-file-name-with-the-current-date-time-in-python)

Comment: The problem here is that I am unable to determine how I will be able to change the file name inside the open('/C:/Users/SET/Desktop/TEST/TEST/test_test_test_file_20201001.csv','rb'). I already tried creating the file name in a variable and run it inside open() but it just looks for the file name which is available in "". I aplogize if I am not able to explain better. Still learning my way through pyhton

Comment: This is a more accurate duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713643/how-to-add-the-date-to-the-file-name

Comment: I figured it out.Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to update the file path on a daily basis

The code below will create the file name based on the current date:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
file_name = f'test_test_test_file_{today.year}{today.month:02}{today.day:02}.csv'
print(file_name)
```

output

```
test_test_test_file_20201007.csv
```

Comment: I would use `strftime` instead to just extract the info you want: `datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Or use f-strings width parameters so both the month and day is correctly formatted without the need for any ternary logic: `f'test_test_test_file_{today.year}{today.month:02}{today.day:02}.csv'`